# Performance of DensityPlot3D with non-opaque Graphics3D

Tags: plotting, rendering, performance

Does anyone have problems with performance of graphics combining DensityPlot3D and any other non-opaque Graphics3D? If I combine ListDensityPlot3D (very simple one, first from documentation) with only 1 fully opaque sphere, FPS are high:

```
data = Table[
   x y z, {z, -1, 1, 2/40.}, {y, -1, 1, 2/40.}, {x, -1, 1, 2/40.}];
densityplot = ListDensityPlot3D[data];
sphere = Graphics3D[{Opacity[1], Sphere[{10, 10, 10}, 5]}];
Show[densityplot, sphere]
```

[image]

But If i change the opacity to 0.5, performance drops dramatically:

[image]

(there is a FPS counter on the top)

Is it normal? 10 FPS are still enough for interaction, but when plots get massive it is completly non-functional.

Mathematica 12.1, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050, Drivers version: 30.0.15.1179, drivers date: 10.02.2022, DirectX: 12 (FL 12.1), Windows 10

Comment: In vs 13 there is no example for an animated ListPlot3D

Comment: It's not animation, it is just rotating the plot with mouse